# How do I delete nonlocal variables in python3 using a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to supply either strings with variable names or variables themselves to a function, and for that function to delete them from the scope just outside it. Here is code illustrating what I'd like to do:

```py
def delete_variables_by_name(*varnames):
    for name in varnames:
        print(f"deleting {name}")
        del globals()[name]  # I want to do this but with "nonlocals()"
    # I'd now do some other stuff here regarding caching etc

variable = "this should stay"
variable_2 = "this should stay too"

def outer_fun():
    variable = "some value"
    variable_2 = "another_value"
    delete_variables_by_name("variable", "variable_2")
    try:
        print(
            f"Vars within outer_fun: variable={locals()['variable']}, "
            f"variable_2={locals()['variable_2']}"
        )
        print("It didn't work, variables within outer_fun should be deleted")
    except KeyError:
        print('Good, it worked!')

outer_fun()

try:
    print(f"globals: variable={variable}, variable_2={variable_2}")
    print("Good, the global variables were not deleted")
except NameError:
    print('Oh dear, global variables were deleted, only want to delete those in outer_fun')
```

If a `nonlocals()` equivalent to `globals()` existed, I could edit `delete_variables_by_name` and the above code would do what I want.

Is there a sensible way to do this in python?

(Why do I want this? I would like to do additional things post deletion, and would do this in many places in my codebase - if that code would change in future, `delete_variables_by_name` would be the only place I'd need to update my code, otherwise I'd need to hunt for every `del` statement in my codebase and change in all those places.)

Comment: "I would like to supply either strings with variable names or variables themselves to a function, and for that function to delete them from the scope just outside it. " There is no sane way to do this. Almost certainly, you don't want to design your program this way.

Comment: You could use `inspect` and walk back the frames to the caller... but note, you can't actually dynamically modify function local scopes in CPython anyway.

Comment: You can try deleting in the scope of the enclosing function

Comment: Honestly, this all sounds very suspicious. For example, I think I've actually used `del` maybe a handful of times ever, and usually when I want to remve something from a module-level namespace... why are you deleting variables in a bunch of places to begin with?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - I'm unsure why this is insane and suspicious to you. I would like to do this to free memory and, as my final bracketed comment says, then perform other cleanup (its simply `torch.cuda.clear_cache()` at the moment, but likely will update in future...hence why I'd like to do this with a function!

Comment: ... `del` doesn't free memory. Seriously, look at any major python code base, you'll see very scant use of `del variable`. This all sounds insane because what you are asking for would require super hacky introspection of the stack frame, **especially** if you want to be able to "pass in the variable itself", because *note*, you don't pass variables, you pass *objects*

Comment: And, if `outer_fun()` was not a function, but just written in the clear as the main script, I can do exactly what I want with `globals()`...so I'm asking how to do the same with `outer_fun()` as a function.

Comment: @JamesOwers there's no real way to do this, you can't dynamically modify local namespaces in CPython. Without some *serious* hacking

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - "`del` doesn't free memory" - it will when I invoke the garbage collection or `torch.cuda.clear_cache()`

Comment: @JamesOwers no, you fundamentally don't understand python's memory model if you think that.  Local variables are all implicitly `del`'d at the end of a function anyway... regardless, it sounds like you have a fundamentally unsound design if this is what you are relying on.

Comment: Ok @juanpa.arrivillaga - that sounds like an answer to me. If you would like to expand on  why this wont work for all use cases - e.g. clearing gpu memory as posited [here](https://forums.fast.ai/t/clearing-gpu-memory-pytorch/14637/3) - I will happily accept your answer.

Comment: @James that's not true, actually. CPython uses *reference counting* as its main memory management strategy. As *an implementation detail*, as soon as an object's reference count reaches zero, the object is reclaimed *immediately*. The `gc` only handles references cycles.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, oh. my mistake.

Comment: @James what you were saying wasn't totally wrong, like, the fundamental idea was accurate, just a minor quibble about implementation details. But the point you made stands, local variables are all basically `del`'d anyway.